# Is there a way to make a function return a function?

Tags: c++

So in Lua you can do something like this

```lua
local function start(n)
    return function()
        n = n + 1;
        return n;
    end;
end

print(start(1)()); --> 2
```

I've heard of templates though I don't want to have an xy problem, or is there another way

Comment: They are called [Function objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) or Functors. It's just any object that provides a `operator()`.

Comment: Return a `std::function` or a function pointer.

Comment: Closures in C++ have some restrictions that are caused by the lack of Automatic Memory Management. So, you won't get something that is 100% equivalent.

Comment: returning function pointer is also work around

Comment: @JörgWMittag care to clarify what you mean by Automatic Memory Management? C++ certainly DOES NOT lack automatic storage duration, for example.

Comment: @SergeyA: In the Lua example, `n` is captured by reference. In other words, the lifetime of the local variable `n` is extended by an indefinite and unbounded amount of time beyond the lifetime of its enclosing lexical scope. This pretty much *requires* Automatic Memory Management to handle. Lua, Lisp, Scheme, Smalltalk, Ruby, Python, PHP, Haskell, Scala, C♯, F♯, ECMAScript, and countless other languages deal with this without any sort of problem, but in C++, it is not allowed because of the lack of Automatic Memory Management. If C++ *had* Automatic Memory Management, this restriction …

Comment: … wouldn't exist (and neither would `delete`) and the equivalent C++ code would just magically work. If you want, you can replace "AMM" with "Garbage Collection", but I think GC is too restrictive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ you cannot declare a function inside of another function.  Luckily though we can work around that by creating a closure object using a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).  Your code, adapted to that would become

```
template <typename Integer>
auto start(Integer n)
{
    return [n]() mutable { return ++n; };
}
```

And then you would use it like

```
std::cout << start(1)();
```

---

There are couple things to note about the above example.  First, the capture of `n`.  Since the closure object is be returned out of the scope of `start`, we have to capture it by value, otherwise the closure will have a dangling reference.  Secondly, the use of `mutable` in the lambda expression.  That is there because by default the `operator()` is `const`.  That means you could not modify `n`.  Using `mutable` removes the `const` and allows `n` to be modified.

Comment: how about using auto instead of the template? will it work?

Comment: @Mayur You mean like `auto start(auto n) ...`?  No, that doesn't work, t least yet.  It might get added in a future version of C++ though.

Comment: oh, which would be cool then.

Comment: I think you meant `++n`

Comment: @Ayxan Yep.  Fixed.

Comment: what's was wrong with `n++`?

Comment: @Mayur It would return `1` and set `n` to `2`.  `++n` sets `n` to `2` and returns `2`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to return a lambda function object:

```
auto start(int n) {
    return [n]() mutable {
        n = n + 1;
        return n;
    };
}
```

Comment: why to `mutable`?

Comment: @Mayur otherwise `n` will be readonly within the lambda.